# RestSharp send body as text/plain

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

This is my request in postman. It's working.

[image]

I'm trying do the same using RestSharp. My method:

```
    public bool CloseVisit(int visitDateId)
    {
        try
        {
            bool result = true;
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Method = Method.PUT;
            request.Resource = Const.CloseVisitUrl + visitDateId.ToString();
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            Parameter p = new Parameter();
            p.Name = "text/plain";
            p.Type = ParameterType.RequestBody;
            p.ContentType = "text/plain";
            p.Value = sessionId;
            request.AddParameter(p);
            var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request);
            if (response.Result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
                return false;
            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting internal error. Thanks for help.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Your question is too broad to get any meaningful answer. Also the `catch (Exception ex)` is a terrible, terrible idea (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2009/02/19/why-catchexceptionempty-catch-is-bad/)

Comment: so what is your code sending thats different to the working?

Comment: I solved problem.
I added:
request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/plain");    
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/api");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xyz");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
request.AddParameter("text/plain", "Hello World!",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the response is also text type, we should add header "Accept: text/plain"
This works for me:

```
string body = "This is body text";
var client = new RestClient("http://resturl.com");
var request = new RestRequest("/api", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse restResponse = client.Execute(request);
return restResponse.Content;
```